# How would I randomly create typos in a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, random, chatbot

Ok so I'm working on a chatbot and I have a private std::string called m_sResponse. This string is outputted using

```
void print_response() const {
    if(m_sResponse.length() > 0) {
        std::cout << m_sResponse << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I want to create a function that will misspell m_sRensponse let's say 5% of the time so the chatbot seams more human like. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Just let me do the tpying.

Comment: "seams more human like".  Mission accomplished?

Comment: @Chemistpp Let's not forget `m_sRensponse`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it seem more realistic, I'd make a `map<char,vector<char>>` of appropriate 'substitution' keys based off of keyboard layouts (e.g. QWERTY). Basically, it seems more real if your typo is "responsw" than "responsl" since "w" and "e" are next to each other. You'll also want to randomly delete or insert letters too. I'd assign a frequency to "errors" and then a frequency of each kind of error.

Now that you've got this and the other answers handling the randomness aspect (`if(rand(100)<5)`), you should be able to replicate the desired typo handler.

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea but I don't know much about maps. Could you give me an example of what a map of substitution keys would look like?I know I'd have to do something like `replace(vectorObject.begin(), vectorObject.end(), 'W', 'E');`

Comment: You don't really need a `map`: since the elements to be mapped (the letters of the alphabet) are consecutive integers which can be remapped over the [0, 26) range, you can just use a `vector<vector>>`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia That makes it awfully hard to add numbers and other characters in later. Plus foreign languages. OTOH, it handles case without needing to call `tolower`.

Comment: @SuicidalCookie It'll be a bit more complicated than that. Let's assume you have a `map<char, vector<char>> cmap;` already populated and your `string m_sResponse`. Once you've determined to replace the character at position `pos`, you'll need to do something like: `m_sResponse[ pos ] = cmap[ m_sResponse[ pos ] ] [rand( cmap[ m_sResponse[ pos ] ].size() )];`

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I'm starting to get it to work. All great ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
if rand(100) < 5
    randomIndex = rand(string.length())
    randomChar = rand(26)
    string[randomIndex] = randomChar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a random seed and use %5 for like 20% of the time ish.

```
if((rand() % 5) == 0) {
          int t = rand() & m_sResponse.length();
          char a = m_sResponse[t];
          m_sResponse[t] = m_sResponse[t+1];
          m_sResponse[t+1] = a;
}
```

Comment: This throws an error because it is a const.

    Error 1 error C3892: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator []' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const necibot.h 115

Comment: @SuicidalCookie  didn't in [my case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ec2dcbde91f0bab) but the idea is there.  You can just rearrange two letters some of the times.  I think mistypes are as common as a typo.  (I.e.   hlelo instead of hello) though the other guy who suggests a char map has a great idea for logical typos (like i and p for o, but not f for o).